# Locally compact allows shrinking compact neighborhood without hausdorff property?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological space and $Y$ locally compact. Define $\alpha$ relation on $X$. Consider identity relation on $Y$.(i.e. $Y/1=Y$.)

Let $T\subset X\times Y/(\alpha\times 1)$ be open. Then $T'$ preimage of $T$ in $X\times Y$ is product of open sets $U\times V$ with open sets $U\subset X,V\subset Y$. Then the book claims we can assume $V$ to be compact set.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How can one assume $V$ to be compact? Normally, I knew there is a $V'$ smaller neighborhood of $V$ contained in $K$ with $K$ compact by $Y$ locally compact. However, I need to trim down this $\bar{V'}\subset V$ to reduce $K$ to $\bar{V'}$. This is achieved by $Y$ hausdorff property.

Ref. Pg 2 Algebraic Topology Switzer

Comment: Let us reformulate what Switzer says: If $p : X \to X'$ is a quotient map and $Y$ is locally compact, then $p \times id_Y : X \times Y \to X' \times Y$ is a quotient map. Now what is your question? Whether this is true for non-Hausdorff $Y$? If so, what is your definition of locally compact?

Comment: @PaulFrost The main problem I have is that I do not know which definition of locally compactness is being used here. I knew several of them. However, I am guessing he is using the one saying every open neighborhood contains a compact neighborhood.

Comment: @PaulFrost The other question is how to deduce shrinking $K$ to a smaller one without hausdorff property if I am assuming standard definition(i.e. There is a neighborhood contained in a compact set.)

Comment: Switzer is not very explicit in Chapter 0. I believe he assumes that locally compact includes Hausdorff. However, for general topological spaces the only **reasonable** definition of local compactness is that of your first comment. Using this definition, the statement remains true. Try to adapt the proof!

Comment: @PaulFrost Ah in that case, then trimming down procedure is trivial and that 2 definitions are equivalent. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I suggest that you write a short answer and also accept it. This makes it visible at first glance that the question is no onger open,

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to demonstrate 2 definitions of local compactness are equivalent under assumption of hausdorff property.

(a) Every open neighbourhood has a compact neighborhood(i.e. $\forall U,\exists K\subset U$ with $U$ open and $K$ compact.)

(b) For every point there is a compact set containing an open set.

Clearly $a)\implies b)$. It suffices to deal with converse implication.

Take $U\subset K$. It suffices to produce $\bar{W}\subset U$ with $\bar{W}$ compact. Now consider $\partial U\subset K$ is compact by $K$ compact. Use hausdorff property to find a open set $V$ disjoint from $\partial U$'s covering and containing a point $x\in U$. Here we need to use compactness of $\partial U$ to ensure finite intersection. Now $W=U\cap V$ is an open set containing $x$. Note that $\bar{W}\neq K$ for sure as we have removed $\partial U$. So we have found $\bar{W}$ compact neighborhood contained in $U$.

The general case can be handled similarly.